# Any reference on Eisenstein Series for $\Gamma_0(N)$ in $\mathrm{GL}(2)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms

What is the best reference on Eisenstein Series for $\Gamma_0(N)$ in $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$?

For fixed $\Gamma_0(N)$, should there be several Eisenstein series (corresponding to each cusp)?

Comment: Are you assuming trivial central character? The given answers are only for $Psl(2, \mathbb{R})$, and which is fine, depending upon your definition of $\Gamma_0(N)$.

Answer (score 10):

Miyake, already recommended by GH, is a very complete reference, which is perhaps the only place to contain complete proofs about the subject. However, for that reason, and also because
he works with weird modular groups $\Gamma_1(a,b)$ conjugate to but not equal to 
the more familiar $\Gamma_1(ab)$, it is difficult to read.

So I propose another reference which contains a clear complete basis of
Eisenstein series, which are eigenforms for $\Gamma_1(N)$, together with their nebentypus,
and their Hecke eigenvalues : W. Stein, Modular Forms, A Computational Approach, available at
http://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/index.html
. More precisely, see [here](http://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/eisenstein.html#explicit-basis-for-the-eisenstein-subspace).

To get Eisenstein series for $\Gamma_0(N)$ from those for $\Gamma_1(N)$, just restrict to those with trivial nebentypus, that is $\psi \chi=1$ in the notation of the reference given.

And about your question: in weight $>2$, there are as many independent Eisenstein series
as cusps; in weight $2$, the dimension of the Eisenstein subspace is the number of cusp minus 1, because "$E_2$ is missing".

Comment: Stein's book is a good reference, but beware of a typo in Theorem 5.9 which means that some formulae for Eisenstein series with character are not quite correct (some $\psi$'s should be $\bar{\psi}$'s). See http://trac.sagemath.org/sage_trac/ticket/4062 (a bug in the Sage computer algebra system which was traced to an incorrect formula copied from Stein's book). 

Answer (score 6):

For detailed information I recommend "Chapter 7. Eisenstein series" in Miyake: Modular Forms (Springer Verlag, 2006).